# how can I set the value in select option field using angularjs

Tags: angularjs

I am getting the response as below and I would like to adjust those in `select option` tag. How can I set those please suggest the same

```
[null,"a","b","c ","d"]
```

My code is like

```
$http.get('v1/sport').success(function(data) {
    $scope.sports = [];
    //$scope.sports = data.data; 
    angular.forEach(data.data, function(value, key) {
        $scope.sports[value.sport_id] = value.name;
    });
});
```

In view

```
<select name="teamSport"
                      ng-model="player.sport_id"
                      ng-options="sport[player.sport_id] as sport[player.name] for sport in sports"
                      ng-change="changedSport()"
                      required>
                      <option value="" selected="selected">-- Select --</option>
                    </select>
```

---

Comment: here angular select documentation https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/select

Comment: Please share your html?also share $scope.sports data

Comment: have you check

{"sport_id":"1","name":"a"},{"sport_id":"2","name":"b"},{"sport_id":"3","name":"c "},{"sport_id":"4","name":"d"}] || {"sport_id":"3","name":"c "}

Calling this i am getting
{{sports}} || {{sports[player.sport_id]}}

Answer (score 1):

Using ng-repeat and ng-model like [this](http://jsbin.com/pibononehu/1/edit?html,js,output)

```
<select ng-model='value'>
   <option ng-repeat='option in options'>
     {{option}}
   </option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can directly use the data without converting it using forEach.

Here is the script which will render the dropdown using the data you gave in the comment [{"sport_id":"1","name":"a"},{"sport_id":"2","name":"b"},{"sport_id":"3","name":"‌​c"},{"sport_id":"4","name":"d"}]

You can set the selected in the $scope.selected variable.

```js
var myApp = angular.module('myApp', [])

.controller('MyController', ['$scope', function($scope) {
  
      $scope.sports =  [{"sport_id":"1","name":"a"},{"sport_id":"2","name":"b"},{"sport_id":"3","name":"‌​c"},{"sport_id":"4","name":"d"}]; 
  
    $scope.selected = $scope.sports[2];
  
  }]);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>

<div ng-app="myApp">
  
<div ng-controller="MyController">
{{selected}}
<select name="teamSport"
                      ng-model="selected"
                      ng-options="sport as sport.name for sport in sports"
                      ng-change="changedSport()"
                      required>
                      <option value="" selected="selected">-- Select --</option>
                    </select>
  </div>
  </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$http.get('v1/sport') .success(function (data) { $scope.sports = [];  angular.forEach(data.data, function(value, key){ $scope.sports[value.sport_id] = value.name; }); }); 
$http.get('v1/selectedSport') .success(function (data) { $scope.selectedSport = data; });
```

And the view

```
<select 
       ng-model="selectedSport" 
       ng-options="sport[player.sport_id] as sport[player.name] for sport in sports">
</select>
```

Comment: The data given [null,"a","b","c ","d"] doesn't have sport_id and name

Comment: @Siva Not sure that is the question, but then again the question isn't clear...>_< I read the question as setting the selectedItem